# How to convert string into boolean array?

Tags: android

I convert everything in my Android app into string and  add it to a Sqlite database. I use the code below to convert boolean arrays into string, but I dont know how to convert it back from string into boolean array. There spaces between each `true` and `false` in the string. How can I break string at each space into a boolean array?

```
String work= "";
for (int i = 0;i<go.length; i++) {
    work= work+go[i];
    // Do not append comma at the end of last element
    if(i<go.length - 1){
        work = work+" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try googling you will find answer to all your question on previously asked questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: what is go, is it string array?

Comment: oh sorry ya go is the string array

Answer (score 3):

1. Split the string on your separator character (`" "`)
2. Create an array of `boolean`s with the same length of the splitted array of strings
3. Parse one by one them using `Boolean.parseBoolean` method

---

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "true false true false false";

    String[] parts = str.split(" ");

    boolean[] array = new boolean[parts.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
        array[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[i]);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Outputs:

```
[true, false, true, false, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(string);`